# Grammar for ${a^n b^n c^{n+m}}$

Tags: formal-languages, formal-grammars

Can we define a grammar for the following language?

$$L = \{a^n b^n c^{n+m} | n,m>=0\}\,.
$$

I can define one for this:
$$L=\{a^nb^n|n,m>=0\}
$$

> S --> aSb | λ

or this one:
$$L=\{b^nc^{n+m}|n,m>=0\}
$$

> S --> Ac
>   A --> bSc | Sc | λ

but I can't solve the first one, any hint?

Comment: The language is not context free. And it's certainly not regular. What does "of a finite automata" mean?

Comment: Ofcourse you can. But don't try by a context free grammar... this language is not context free.
You can use this grammaer for reference:
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Computability_and_Complexity/Formal_Languages/Chomsky_Hierarchy/Context_Sensitive_Languages#Context_Sensitive_Languages
 Adding the ${c}^*$ at the end should be easy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This gives the language: $L = \{a^n b^n c^n c^m | n,m>=0\}\,.
$

1. S   →   a   b   c C | N | ε
2. N   →   a   N   B   c C | a b   c C
3. c   B   →   W   B
4. W   B   →   W   X
5. W   X   →   B   X
6. B   X   →   B   c
7. b   B   →   b   b
8. C   → c C   |   ε

Comment: can you show me some guidelines on deriving such grammars?

Comment: Well in this case I noticed that the language that you need is extremely close to the very famous and most popular context-sensitive language $a^nb^nc^n$. Then I just needed to put c* on the end. Additionally, we need to modify the starting process to allow for n,m=0. Look closely at the simpler language (on wikipedia) and compare to this one. That should help.

Answer (score 3):

**GRAMMAR FOR THE LANGUAGE:{a^n b^n c^n/n>=1}**

S->abc|A

A->aABc|abc

cB->Bc

bB->bb

**FOR EXAMPLE:INPUT STRING aaabbbccc when n=3**

S->A

->aABc

->aaABcBc (A->aABc)

->aaabcBcBc   (A->abc)

->aaabBccBc   (cB->Bc)

->aaabBcBcc   (cB->Bc)

->aaabbcBcc   (bB->bb)

->aaabbBccc   (cB->Bc)

->aaabbbccc   (bB->bb)

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution which is context-sensitive.

$$G = (N,T,P,S)$$
$$N=\{S,A,B,C\}$$
$$T=\{a,b,c\}$$
$$S=\mbox{start symbol}$$
Production Rules(P):

1. $S \rightarrow aAB\ |\ A\ |\ \epsilon$
2. $A  \rightarrow aAB\ |\ aB$
3. $B \rightarrow bC$
4. $Cb \rightarrow bC$
5. $C \rightarrow cC\ |\ c$

Comment: please notify, if something wrong.

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science Stack Exchange. Please read
http://cs.stackexchange.com/tour, if you have not yet done so. --- --- You do not need $S→aAB$, since you have $A→aAB$. But this grammar does not work because you have no obligation to apply rule 4, so that the $b$ and $c$ can remain mixed. You need one more trick.

Comment: I think the obligation of rule 4 is rule 5. Is it ?

Comment: I do not understand your last comment.  This said, I have not looked at this for 2 years, and I do not really wish to dive into it again.

Comment: To much time has been passed so, that's ok.

Answer (score -1):

Grammar for the language $\{a^nb^nc^n \mid n\ge1\}$:
$S\to aSBC\mid aBC$
$CB\to BC$
$aB\to ab$
$bB\to bb$
$bC\to bc$
$cC\to cc$

Comment: That's a different language than the one the OP is interested in. Furthermore, I'd bet they're interested in context-free grammars.